# Error: Could not download silverlight application. Check web server settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Developing a silverlight page in already existing web application for previewing video files. When I create a asp.net application locally and add silverlight application on the solution it works perfectly. But while I am trying to include into already existing project it throws this error. I have not deployed into the IIS. this happens while debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Check the path to your xap file in your webpage. It should be something like:

```
 /ClientBin/my.xap
```

Also ensure that your xap file is actually in the ClientBin folder. In the web application `Properties`, choose the `Silverlight Applications` tab and add the silverlight project to the list.

Although probably not applicable in your case, this can also occur if you are using iis and haven't registered the correct `mime type` for `.xap` files. It should be set to `application/x-silverlight-app`.

Comment: @Joseph - try using a tool like fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see where the xap is being requested from and what is being returned. It might help you debug the issue.

Comment: yes, there is no error while building, but at runtime, it thorws error

Comment: Is the xp file properly formed. Its just a zip file so open with something like 7zip. Compare the contents to the xap in your working solution.

Comment: Delete the xap in the ClientBin folder and re-compile. Is it recreated?

Answer (score 2):

This is little same with another answer, but I give my detailed solution with image of setting.

In my case, one of my aspx page will load `Zip` and `Xap` files under `ClientBin` Folder, normally it'll load 20 `Zip/Xap` files under `ClientBin\`,

But I found that when building/publishing the project, the `Zip/Xap` files are NOT output to `ClientBin\`, that is `ClientBin` folder is nearly empty.

So my solution is to let the `Zip/Xap` files output to `ClientBin\`, to do this, the setting way can see this article:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/d8e2c92a-4b31-4e4b-a440-4960a8d475b4/how-to-generate-xap-file?forum=silverlightstart

Besides here is the screenshot of my setting, that is `Right click at your Silverlight project > Properties > Silverlight Application`, and you can click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button to add content,

[image]