# Unable to run Silverlight application from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, iis-7, iis-express

I'm in the process of setting up a new machine as a development environment and I'm having issues getting an existing code base that hosts a Silverlight application to work. The code runs fine on all other machines that my team uses.

Here is the error:

> Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application
>   Code: 2104
>   Category: InitializeError
>   Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings

I have had a Google around for some answers on this and I realize there is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4040416/308012) on StackOverflow already, but it does not provide enough information and the answers have not worked for me.

I am attempting to run the solution through Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, using IIS Express 7.5 integration (as opposed to the Cassini web server). This approach works perfectly fine on all other machines, except for this one.

I have found that if I specify to use full IIS integration (instead of Express) and select the **SilverlightTestPage.aspx** as the start up page, then the application runs (although not perfectly). Also, if I publish the application and host it on IIS, it again works fine. However, when running through Cassini or IIS Express 7.5 integration, or when trying to get it to run through the **Default.aspx** or correct start up page it does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas what this might be? I've already checked that the MIME type in IIS is correct (not sure if I can do this in IIS Express as well?) and that the XAP files are building into the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check MIME types in IIS Express configuration file %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config and make sure that you have MIME types set correctly and restart IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the aspx file whether it has the "minRuntimeVersion" correctly for the Silverlight plug in.

```
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0"/>
```

also check the following link for hosting the Silverlight application .

[Configuring IIS for silverlight](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications)